# Does OpenBSD have anything equivalent to Debian's /etc/network/if-up.d/ scripts?

Tags: dhcp, openbsd

I want to run a script **after** an OpenBSD interface has been configured (dynamic IP address assigned, routes configured, etc.) I can't find anything in [the hostname.if man page](https://man.openbsd.org/hostname.if) about this; does such a feature exist in OpenBSD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can run shell commands from hostname.if, you might find ifstated(8) a better fit.